# Creating and working with exact differentials in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, calculus, differentiation

I am trying to figure out how to create and manipulate [exact differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential) (algebraic treatment of Leibniz notation) in SymPy. To be clear, it is well known that

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
x, y=symbols('x, y')
f=Function('f')(x, y)
Derivative(f, x)
```

yields

[image]

In the case above, the exact differential is

[image]

For a physicist this is especially needed given the kind of abuse we do to the chain rule but also for simple things like `V = A \ell` and `dV = dA d\ell`, when working with integrals or this classic physics [abuse of the Leibniz notation](http://pruffle.mit.edu/3.00/Lecture_21_web/node1.html) that occurs all the time in thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something very naive for *univariate* functions.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x  = Symbol(' x')
>>> dx = Symbol('dx')
>>> def f (x):
...     return x**3
>>> def g (x):
...     return sin(x)
```

Let us take the differentials of `f` and `g` using their Taylor expansions in differential `dx`:

```
>>> f(x+dx).series(dx,0,2) - f(x)
3*dx*x**2 + O(dx**2)
>>> g(x+dx).series(dx,0,2) - g(x)
dx*cos(x) + O(dx**2)
```

where, by definition, `O(dx**2)` is zero. Of course, we could also use differentiation (`diff`):

```
>>> diff(x**3,x) * dx
3*dx*x**2
>>> diff(sin(x),x) * dx
dx*cos(x)
```